# 'net use' , mapping network drive without stored credentials

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2019

is it possible to map a drive in the batch file without haveing to use the password in the command `net use w: \\(server)\lantalk password:***** \user:*****` is it possible to use the stored password within the server

Comment: Short answer: No as that would be a major security breach.

Answer (score 0):

> **is it possible to map a drive in the batch file without haveing to use the password in the command**

Yes. I do this all the time on a shared network of Windows PCs where the computers have a common authentication arrangement or just trust each other. I find it is normally more convenient to create persistent connections than to run batch files though. Perhaps there are other use cases where a batch file would be useful.

> **is it possible to use the stored password within the server**

No. Not in the sense I suspect you mean. People who create security arrangements intend that they cannot be trivially bypassed.

Comment: and is it possible to use credential manager from the batch file in order to map a drive

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for username and password while the .bat is running, withou saving them in the .bat file.

example:

```
set /p username=Insert username:
set /p password=Insert password:
echo =======================================
net use Z: /delete
net use Z: \\server.yourdomain.local\shared-folder %password% /user:yourdomain\%username%
```